# Remote loading of video on channel with moderation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I apologize for my English. I use the translator. I need to make the page through which users could load video on youtube. At the same time not to publish at once. And at first most to carry out moderation. Since I want to attract users from the different countries. It will be a competition where participants will be from the different countries, and I will support them residents of the same countries. Will be abruptly) But a big problem that there is no opportunity to load video directly on youtube channel. Maybe someone already did and will prompt something?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  You need to show us what you have done to solve your problem not just describe your problem.

Comment: What have you done so far? please provide minimal, complete and verifiable code. If you encountered any error, please also include you logs.